# How to select different row in a matrix in Matlab every time?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a matrix which has distinct rows selected from another matrix.

For Example, I have a `10x3` matrix `A`

```
A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
13    14    15
16    17    18
19    20    21
22    23    24
25    26    27
28    29    30
```

Now I want to create a new matrix `B` of size `2 X 3` from `A` in a iterative process in such a way that the matrix `B` should consist different rows in each iteration (max iteration = 5)

**My Pseudo-code:**

```
for j=1:5
  create matrix 'B' by selecting 2 rows randomly from 'A', which should be different
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`randperm`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to mess up the rows randomly and then take two rows in each iteration successively in order.

```
iterations = 4;
permu = randperm(size(A,1));
out = A(permu(1:iterations*2),:);

for ii = 1:iterations
    B = out(2*ii - 1:2*ii,:)
end
```

**Results:**

```
B =
22    23    24
25    26    27

B =
 1     2     3
13    14    15

B =
19    20    21
16    17    18

B =
 7     8     9
10    11    12
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....actually i don't want to select maximum possible combinations i.e total no. of iterations could be less than 5 also. But i want 2 things: (1) a new created matrix B doesn't consist common rows of A, (2) in every iteration the rows of B doesn't match with the previous rows of B

Comment: @PrateekSinghal Edited for variable number of iterations. Just change the value of the `iterations` variable and that should work.